Why is my ARIMA model's prediction a straight line?
I am trying to create an ARIMA model to predict road traffic for a single node using the PEMS08 dataset preprocessed for ASTGCN. I used the statsmodels library together with the auto_arima function of the pmdarima library to automatically determine the best parameters for the ARIMA model. However, when I run the predictions on the test data, the result is a constant straight line, which does not reflect the variations observed in the original time series at all.
Flow chart
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pmdarima import auto_arima
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error

# Caricamento del dataset preprocessato per ASTGCN
data = np.load('data/PEMS08/PEMS08_r1_d0_w0_astcgn.npz')


# Estrazione della serie temporale per il nodo 0
data_node_0 = data['train_target'][:, 0, :]  # (num_samples, num_for_predict)

# Riorganizzazione dei dati in una singola serie temporale
time_series_node_0 = data_node_0.flatten()

# Divisione dei dati in train e test
train_size = int(len(time_series_node_0) * 0.8)
train, test = time_series_node_0[:train_size], time_series_node_0[train_size:]

# Utilizzo di auto_arima per determinare i migliori parametri ARIMA
stepwise_model = auto_arima(train, seasonal=False, trace=True, error_action='ignore', suppress_warnings=True)
print(stepwise_model.summary())

# Creazione del modello ARIMA con i migliori parametri trovati
tuned_order = stepwise_model.order
model = ARIMA(train, order=tuned_order)
model_fit = model.fit()

# Predizione sui dati di test
start = len(train)
end = len(train) + len(test) - 1
predictions = model_fit.predict(start=start, end=end, typ='levels')

# Valutazione delle prestazioni del modello
mae = mean_absolute_error(test, predictions)
mse = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
mape = np.mean(np.abs((test - predictions) / test)) * 100

print(f'MAE: {mae:.4f}')
print(f'RMSE: {rmse:.4f}')
print(f'MAPE: {mape:.4f}%')

# Grafico delle previsioni rispetto ai valori reali
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(test, label='Valori Reali', color='blue')
plt.plot(predictions, label='Previsioni ARIMA', color='red')
plt.title('Confronto tra Previsioni ARIMA e Valori Reali per il Nodo 0')
plt.xlabel('Tempo')
plt.ylabel('Valore del Flusso')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()


Trend seasonal residual chart

The data does not look like it has much 1-day autocorrelation. I guess estimated coefficients for 1 day are small so prediction is just the mean. For daily traffic data, I would use at least a weakly seasonal effect in the model. (I guess Sundays will not have the same amount of traffic as weekdays). Other effects will be holidays or special events.

I wanted to use the ARIMA model to make a baseline in comparison with the most recent models, but it gives me layered results even if in the various papers it gives consistent results, that is, worse than the current ones, and I wanted to do it for the PEMS dataset. I tried both with the preprocessed data of ASTGCN but still I can't replicate the same results of the papers, any suggestions? I updated the code using the preprocessed data of ASTGCN

What happens if you don't ignore errors and don't suppress warnings?

Edited question with new approach, but have the same problem @Josef
